# Modsecurity doesn't work correctly on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, mod-security, mod-security2

I installed modsecurity version 2.9.1 64 bit but i got error

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ModSecurity
Date:          6/3/2016 3:53:36 PM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-RNA83N2IDID
Description:
The description for Event ID 1 from source ModSecurity cannot be found. 
Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. 
You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
```

After I had gotten this error, I installed visual studio 2013 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 and x64. I didn't install anything else. I still get error. How can i fix that?

Thank your answer

Answer (score 0):

This waning may be safely ignored, since it shows matching pattern in the SQL queries.
In fact this is a bug.
If you are using plesk then follow this steps.
To exclude appearing these messages in the EventViewer, add the following string in the
Tools & Settings > Web Application Firewall(ModSecurity) > Settings > Custom directives:
Type SecDebugLogLevel 1
And Apply.
For more info :
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004570354-Why-does-ModSecurity-show-many-warnings-in-the-EventViewer-

Comment: This is my modsecurity project which I used senior project in university. Maybe it could work fine with knowledge. I couldn't remember modsecurity problem since it was done long time ago, but maybe someone can benefit from. Thanks for your reply